# Use socket.io in browser via ES6 import

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, socket.io, es6-modules

I'd like to import the socket.io-client library as ES6 import.

---

Using following import syntax:

`import io from 'socket.io-client.js';`

returns the error **Requested module does not provide an export"**.

[image: error 1]

---

As a workaround I was using following code to create a module from the socket.io code:

in **socket.io.mjs**

```
// import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js';
import './socket.io-client.js';
export default globalThis.io;
```

But the error message this time says **"Cannot set property 'io' of undefined."**

[image: error 2]

---

**So to my question - Is there any possibility to import socket.io on the client-browser side via ES6 imports?**

Note that I'd really like to avoid using < script >-tags, loading the code myself or loading by require.js, browserify and co!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like I've figured out an answer myself.

This code should do the job:

**inside socket.io-client.js**

```
const exports = null, module = {};
... // the socket.io-client.js library code
export default module.exports;
```